# Why does Move-AzResource fail to move resources with dependencies within the same resource group?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to write a powershell script that automates aggregating all resources to the same resource group, but I'm hitting errors which stops the execution of Move-AzResource.

```
$resources = Get-AzResource
#Skip already migrated resources:
$resources = $resources | Where-Object {$_.ResourceGroupName -ne "spMigrateResourceGroup"}

$groups = $resources | Group-Object ResourceGroupName
$groups = $groups.Name

$groups | ForEach-Object {
    $group = $_

    $groupResources = $resources | Where-Object ResourceGroupName -eq $group
    $groupResourceIds = $groupResources.ResourceId

    $response = Move-AzResource -DestinationResourceGroupName $resourceGroupTarget `
    -ResourceId $groupResourceIds -Force -Verbose -Debug

    Write-Host $response
}
```

Since Move-AzResource is constrained to move resources within the same resource group at a time, I grab resourceId's within the same resource group and initiate Move-AzResource, but I hit errors like:

```
DEBUG: ============================ HTTP RESPONSE ============================

Status Code:
BadRequest

Headers:
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Pragma                        : no-cache
x-ms-failure-cause            : gateway
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-writes: 1199
x-ms-request-id               : e0f0f5e3-faaf-44ad-b3e4-61e51ad89a84
x-ms-correlation-request-id   : e0f0f5e3-faaf-44ad-b3e4-61e51ad89a84
x-ms-routing-request-id       : SOUTHCENTRALUS:20200331T165747Z:e0f0f5e3-faaf-44ad-b3e4-61e51ad89a84
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options        : nosniff
Date                          : Tue, 31 Mar 2020 16:57:46 GMT

Body:
{
  "error": {
    "code": "MultipleErrorsOccurred",
    "message": "Multiple error occurred: BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest. Please see details.",
    "details": [
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/SqlIaasExtension' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/joindomain' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS02/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS02/extensions/BGInfo' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS01/extensions/BGInfo' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG02/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG02/extensions/BGInfo' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG01/extensions/BGInfo' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2DFS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows' is not a top level resource."
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2DFS01/extensions/BGInfo' is not a top level resource."
      },
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/      },
      {                                                                                                                  Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2BIS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows' is not a top level resource."
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/      },
      {                                                                                                                  Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2BIS01/extensions/BGInfo' is not a top level resource."
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/      },
      {                                                                                                                  Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2ADS01/extensions/Microsoft.Powershell.DSC' is not a top level resource."
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/
      },
      {
        "code": "ResourceNotTopLevel",
        "message": "Identifier '//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I believe when it says "ResourceNotTopLevel" it's saying it's a dependency and is supposed to be moved together with the top level resource that controls it, like a database server with databases. But I'm fairly sure the dependencies and dependents are packaged within the same resource group, and is therefore provided within the Move-AzResource command. In fact, I can initiate the same command on the Azure Portal by using the "Move" feature of resource groups, and it successfully moves every resource in the group to a target resource group - which suggests to me everything necessary for the move is in the resource group.

So I guess my question is two fold: why is this happening (especially since it seems to work on the portal), and why doesn't Move-AzResource at least move forward with moving the resources it can? The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/move-resource-group-and-subscription#frequently-asked-questions) suggest that the command does its best to move what it can, but Move-AzResource seems to stop upon trying to validate some of the bad requests. Here are the resources sent with one iteration of the loop:

```
Body:
{
  "targetResourceGroup": "//resourceGroups/spMigrateResourceGroup",
  "resources": [
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stoae2arscache",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/frankcloudshellstorage",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.SqlVirtualMachine/SqlVirtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/VNET-SPOC-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/SQL-EXTERNAL",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/SQL2014SP3-EXTERNAL",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/PIP-VNG-VNET-SPOC-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/PIP-SPOCAE2NST01-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/PIP-RDG-SPOC-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/PIP-EXTERNAL",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/PIP-DFS",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/PIP-ADS",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/NSG-SPOC-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/spocae2nst01155",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2S17W19-01",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2RDS02-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2RDS01-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2RDG02-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2RDG01-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2DFS01-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2BIS02-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2BIS01-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/NIC-SPOCAE2ADS01-1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/localNetworkGateways/LNG-VNET-SPOC-AWU",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ILB-SPOCAFCAE2-SSRS",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers/ILB-SPOCAFCAE2-SQL",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-SPOCAE2DFS01",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/schedules/shutdown-computevm-SPOCAE2ADS01",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/SqlIaasExtension",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/joindomain",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS02/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS02/extensions/BGInfo",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS02",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS01/extensions/BGInfo",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS01",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG02/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG02/extensions/BGInfo",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG02",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG01/extensions/BGInfo",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG01",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2DFS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2DFS01/extensions/BGInfo",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2DFS01",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2BIS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2BIS01/extensions/BGInfo",
    "//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2BIS01",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2ADS01/extensions/Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2ADS01",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SQL_TEMPDB_H",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SQL_OSDISK",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SQL_LOG_G",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SQL_DATA_F",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SQL2014SP3_TEMPDB_H",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SQL2014SP3_OSDISK",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SQL2014SP3_LOG_G",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SQL2014SP3_DATA_F",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2S17W19_TEMPDB_H",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2S17W19_OSDISK",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2S17W19_LOG_G",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2S17W19_DATA_F",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2RDS02_OSDISK.vhd",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2RDS01_OSDISK.vhd",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2RDG02_OSDISK.vhd",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2RDG01_OSDISK.vhd",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2NST01_OsDisk_1_1e0ef5ca87c34a0d9283d37b3c531910",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2DFS01_OSDISK.vhd",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2DFS01_DFS_DISK_1",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2BIS02_OSDISK.vhd",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2BIS01_OSDISK.vhd",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/SPOCAE2ADS01_OSDISK.vhd",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/AS-SPOC-SQL-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/AS-SPOC-RDS-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/AS-SPOC-RDG-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/AS-SPOC-DFS-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/AS-SPOC-BIS-AE2",
    "//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/availabilitySets/AS-SPOC-ADS-AE2"
  ]
}
```

Note: I cut out the subscriptions from the errors provided.

Update: Here is the error message preceding the expanded debug log:

```
Message        : MultipleErrorsOccurred : Multiple error occurred: BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest,BadRequest. Please see details.
StackTrace     :    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.ResourceManagerCmdletBase.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo capturedException)
                    at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.ResourceManagerCmdletBase.EndProcessing()
                    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.Complete()
Exception      : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Entities.ErrorResponses.ErrorResponseMessageException
InvocationInfo : {Move-AzResource}
Line           :     $response = Move-AzResource -DestinationResourceGroupName $resourceGroupTarget `

Position       : At ...\aggregator.ps1:82 char:17
                 + … $response = Move-AzResource -DestinationResourceGroupName $resourceGr …
                 +
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow,
I'd like to know what is the Errors you're getting while running what you're running. we don't mind the subscription information we would like to have the error itself.

Comment: @JoseOrtega Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From resources, remove all `.../extensions/xxx` resources. i.e.:

```
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/SqlIaasExtension",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/joindomain",
"//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS02/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS02/extensions/BGInfo",
"//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDS01/extensions/BGInfo",
"//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG02/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG02/extensions/BGInfo",
"//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2RDG01/extensions/BGInfo",
"//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2DFS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2DFS01/extensions/BGInfo",
"//resourceGroups/rg-spoc-ae2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2BIS01/extensions/SiteRecovery-Windows",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2BIS01/extensions/BGInfo",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2ADS01/extensions/Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
```

If we take this machine (`SPOCAE2S17W19`) and associated resources as an example:

```
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/SqlIaasExtension",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/joindomain",
"//resourceGroups/RG-SPOC-AE2/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19",
```

The "top level" group in this case is:

```
.../virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19
```

The other resources under it:

```
.../virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/SqlIaasExtension
.../virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19/extensions/joindomain
```

Are not "top level groups".

These extensions will be automatically moved with the main "top level" group, e.g. `.../virtualMachines/SPOCAE2S17W19`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can prevent this from happening by doing:

```
$topResources = $resources | Where-Object { -not $_.ParentResource}
```

Found out from [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10246).